# Access Redis connection pool using Spring Data Redis without Reflection API

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

Please help me here with the solution.
I want to monitor and periodically log information about the Redis Connection Pool usage in my application. I am using use Redis via spring-data-redis RedisTemplate object. I know that we can access pool through Reflection API as below. Since the pool is accessing through Reflection, during SAST scan we will be getting '**Access Specifier Manipulation**' along with the description as:

> The AccessibleObject API allows the programmer to get around the access control checks provided by Java access specifiers. In particular it enables the programmer to allow a reflected object to bypass Java access controls and in turn change the value of private fields or invoke private methods, behaviors that are normally disallowed.
> In this case the dangerous method you are using is setAccessible()

```
@Autowired
private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;
private void logData(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            JedisConnectionFactory factory = (JedisConnectionFactory)redisConnectionFactory;
            if(factory != null){
                Field poolField = JedisConnectionFactory.class.getDeclaredField("pool");
                if(poolField != null){
                    poolField.setAccessible(true);
                    Pool<Jedis> jedisPool = (Pool<Jedis>)poolField.get(factory);
                    if(jedisPool!=null){
                        int activeNum = jedisPool.getNumActive();
                        int idleNum = jedisPool.getNumIdle();
                        int waitNum = jedisPool.getNumWaiters();
                        long maxBorrowWaitMs = jedisPool.getMaxBorrowWaitTimeMillis();
                        long meanBorrowWaitMs = jedisPool.getMeanBorrowWaitTimeMillis();
                        redisMonitorDetails = redisMonitorDetails+ "getNumActive="+activeNum + " NumIdle="+idleNum+ " NumWaiters="+waitNum + " MaxBorrowWaitTimeMillis="+maxBorrowWaitMs
                                +" MeanBorrowWaitTimeMillis="+meanBorrowWaitMs;
                    }                     
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exe) {
            loggingService.error("Exception during logging in ExceptionHandlerController: " + exe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use [Apache FieldUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) so reflection API called in library instead of your code.

Comment: Updated the code using Apache FieldUtils as below. Now, SAST scan is not reporting this issue.
`Pool<Jedis> jedisPool = (Pool<Jedis>) FieldUtils.readField(JedisConnectionFactory.class, "pool", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code using Apache FieldUtils as below. Now, SAST scan is not reporting this issue.

```
Pool<Jedis> jedisPool = (Pool<Jedis>) FieldUtils.readField(JedisConnectionFactory.class, "pool", true);
```